# Setting and using environment variable in docker alpine in the same line in shell

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I want to set and use the environment variable in alpine shell in the following manner

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:latest /bin/sh -c MY_VAR=mytext;  echo $MY_VAR
```

However, it doesn't print out anything. How do I do this correctly?

## EDIT

More, specifically it doesn't work inside the docker-compose like this

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  tree:
    image: alpine:latest
    entrypoint: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "MY_VAR=mytext; echo ${MY_VAR}"]
```

`docker-compose run tree` gives me a blank string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-e` or `--env` option in `docker run`:

```
docker run --rm -it -e MY_VAR=mytext alpine:latest /bin/sh -c 'echo "$MY_VAR"'
```

```
mytext
```

It is important to quote the command line you're using for the container.

Even this should print correct value of variable `MY_VAR`:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine:latest /bin/sh -c 'MY_VAR=mytext; echo "$MY_VAR"'
```

---

For the second part of `docker-compose` use this `docker-compose.yml` with `environment` section and print it with double `$$`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  tree:
    environment:
      - MY_VAR=mytext
    image: alpine:latest
    container_name: alpine
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/ash
      - -c
      - 'echo $$MY_VAR'
```

And check output with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

```
Recreating alpine ... done
Attaching to alpine
alpine  | mytext
alpine exited with code 0
```

Comment: Check another update with `echo $$MY_VAR` to print your variable.

Comment: @anhubva Thanks for your answer. I want to run one service which will find the package's latest version with `apt list packageName` then pass this value into env variable. And second service of docker-compose.yml will use this env var value for tagging its image. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Does `apt list packageName` have to be run inside newly created image and then use it's output for creating another docker image. This sounds like a requirement for new question.

Comment: :) Yes you are right. I just wanted to create a new compose which has one container will find out which version of app will be installed and pass this value out to the parent level. And second service of compose will get this using environment variable and tag its image after building.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to put powershell command for setting and reading env var:

[image]

```
PS C:\> $SELAM=$(docker run -t --rm alpine echo "naber") ; docker run -t --rm -e SELAM=$SELAM alpine /bin/sh -c "echo abi $SELAM";
```